# Loading many images from external storage to ImageViews in a ListView

Tags: android, performance, listview, bitmap, imageview

My app requires a file browser that allows to browse and choose some files. I have written one and it works. To display thumbnails for files that are images I use

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(image)
```

While this works, for directories that contain hundreds of images, this process is very slow, since the code above would be executed for every image file there. For some larger directory, the activity just exits (from too much memory required by that operation I assume).

I realise that there are ways to improve this, like scaling down images, so bitmaps aren't created from e.g. 12MB image files to only be displayed in a 100x100 ImageView, but is this the way to go? Is there a more efficient way of loading many image files into bitmaps to be displayed in ImageViews as thumbnails in a ListView?

Comment: It would be better to use one of the libraries built just for this kind of thing. A few of the more popular ones are [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), and [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/).